# compare each column of 2 tables and write matching rows in a 3rd table using loop in python

Tags: python, mysql

compare each column of 2 tables and write matching rows in a 3rd table and non-matching rows as "Not Mapped" in 3rd table using loop in python:

Compare first column of table A to first column of Table B, if this is true, then compare 2nd column of Table A with 2nd column of Table B, if this is also TRUE, compare 3rd column of Table A with 3rd column of Table B, if this is also True; then write matching rows into a new table C else write in table C as "Not Mapped"

I am not able to write proper code for this since I am new to python. Any help would be appreciated.

I have 2 tables:

```
 Table A
 employeeiD employee, managerID, DirectorID, Date
 12          A          100         234      2017-01-01
 13          B          101         235      2017-01-01
 14          C          104         234      2017-01-02
 15          D          101         236      2017-01-01
```

and Table B as:

```
 Table B:
 employeeID   managerID    DirectorID   Director
 12           100            234        X
 12           101            235        Y
 12           101            236        Z
 13           102            236        W
 14           104            234        V
 17           105            239        U
```

and my Table C contains following column:
employeeid, managerid, directorid, director, Date

and this table C should have output as:

```
  Table C:
  employeeid   managerid   directorid   director   date
  12           100         234          X          2017-01-01
  14           104         234          V          2017-01-02
```

Following code I am trying:

```
cursor.execute(""" select * from employee """)
results = cursor.fetchall()

for result in results:
    employeeID = result[0]
    managerID = result[2]
    DirectorID = result[3]
    Date = result[4]

cursor.execute(""" select * from manager """)

dataall = cursor.fetchall()

for data in dataall:
    employee = data[0]
    manager = data[1]
    Director = data[2]
    Director_tableb = data[3]

    i = 0
    j = 0
    while i < len(dataall) and j < len(results):
        for result in results:
            if employeeID == employee:
                for data in dataall:
                    if (employeeID == employee) and (managerID == manager) and (DirectorID == Resource):
                        cursor.execute(""" Insert into Table_C (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s) """, (employeeID, managerID, DirectorID, Director_tableb, Date))
                        cursor_db.commit()
                        i =+ 1
                        j =+ 1
```

Comment: I would first like to recommend you to try to write some code that should work the way you want it.

Then, I have some questions about what you are expecting as the result : what would the "true" be when comparing two columns ? What is the format of the tables ? What should be the format of the resulting table ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now, that's some content to work with.
As it is often the case with my answer, I will try to give you a working solution rather than an optimized one.

First, I'll store the results gotten from the first table in a few lists.

```
cursor.execute(""" select * from employee """)
results = cursor.fetchall()

employeeIDs = []
managerIDs = []
directorIDs = []
dates = []
for result in results:
    employeeIDs.append(result[0])
    managerIDs.append(result[2])
    directorIDs.append(result[3])
    dates.append(result[4])
```

Now, I'll get the content from the 2nd table and filling the 3rd table at the same time.

```
cursor.execute(""" select * from manager """)

dataall = cursor.fetchall()

for data in dataall:
    employee = data[0]
    manager = data[1]
    director = data[2]
    director_tableb = data[3]

    i=0
    while (i<len(employeeIDs)):
        if (employeeIDs[i] == employee) & (managerIDs[i] == manager) & (directorIDs[i] == director):
            cursor.execute(""" Insert into Table_C (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s) """, (employeeIDs[i], managerIDs[i], directorIDs[i], director_tableb, dates[i]))
            cursor_db.commit()
            i=len(employeeIDs)
        i =+ 1
```

What I do : I loop over the elements of the 2nd table, and try to see for each element if it is also present in the first table.
If the element is present in the first table (if the condition of the if is true), then I put an end to the current inner loop and add the desired values to table C.
If the element is not found, then we'll move on the next data from the 2nd table.

I wrote this answer assuming the code you wrote with the cursors was correct, but if anything does not work as intended, tell me, so  I can correct my answer.

If any clarification about what I did/why I did them is required, feel free to ask them.
If you have some ways to improve my code, do not hesitate to tell me so.

Comment: The issue with my code is, loop is running infinite times, and same issue i am getting with your code, after entering first row into table C, it keeps running for infinite times and no further data is entered into Table C (if I do not use i<(len(employeeids) inside while loop) since using this line giving me error of index out of range.

Comment: @aalloo I made a mistake when I re-affected i in the if. I changed it, so as to change the value of i after pushing the content to the db